# The position of "that-adverbial clause" within sentence

Tags: clauses

I assume that "he was late at the meeting" is that-adverbial clause.

So, the sentences below are correct ?

1. That he was late at the meeting, we couldn't have started our discussion on the security of IT systems.
2. We couldn't have started our discussion on the security of IT systems 
   that he was late at the meeting.

Comment: You are not using the *that*-clause correctly.  Read about the words **since** and **because**.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, "He was late at the meeting" is non-idiomatic usage to a native English speaker. Here are two constructions that would work using your examples (please note that neither is a "that-clause").

> "**Since** he was late **arriving** at the meeting, we couldn't start our discussion on the security of the IT systems."

Or,

> "We couldn't start our discussion on the security of the IT systems, **because** he was late getting to the meeting."

When using a "that-adverbial clause," it is important to make sure it modifies the **verb** rather than a subject. Here is an example.

> "That he was late for the meeting **was irritating**, but it was not the reason we fired him."